# Bind function returning btVector3 with luabind

Tags: luabind, bullet

I'm trying to bind class using btVector3. Binding btVector3 with constructor works fine. Binding functions like:

```
void SetPosition(const btVector3& position)
```

works fine, but binding this:

```
btVector3 GetPosition()
```

gives me following error:

> error C2719: 'unnamed-parameter': formal parameter with
>   __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned

I understand that btVector3 is aligned, how to fix/workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it's the exact same problem (and if it's still relevant to you, almost two months on), but I was having trouble binding Bullet btTransforms using Luabind. For instance, this gave the same error you described:

```
void bindBtTransform(lua_State *L) {
    luabind::module(L)
    [
        luabind::class_<btTransform>("btTransform")
            // constructors
            .def(luabind::constructor<>())

            // methods
            // INCORRECT -------------------------------------------------------
            .def("getOrigin", &btTransform::getOrigin)
    ];

    return;
}
```

However, when I gave the full signature of the getOrigin() function, it worked:

```
void bindBtTransform(lua_State *L) {
    luabind::module(L)
    [
        luabind::class_<btTransform>("btTransform")
            // constructors
            .def(luabind::constructor<>())

            // methods
            // CHANGE TO THIS-------------------------------------------------
            .def("getOrigin", (const btVector3& (btTransform::*)() const)&btTransform::getOrigin)
    ];

    return;
}
```

Hope that works for you; my problems cleared right up when I made the change.

I'm still getting the error now, but only when I define the multiplication operator for btQuaternions. I'm hoping it's a similar fix.